# Putting Logic in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I'm writing an Android application where a user can type into an element within a currency list, then the other elements would be updated based on the input. I'm weighing two approaches.

1- Putting the conversion logic within the adapter itself

2- Having the presentation layer pass the data to the domain, where the calculation happens and is then returned to and rendered by the presentation layer.

While the second approach looks cleaner to me, I think it's a bit of over-engineering in this case, especially that there is no business outcome here rather than a result than is never stored or used for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on your functional domain.

1. If it's just something allowing you to do business logic after that, I would put it in the adapter itself, like you say.
2. But, if your domain is about currency conversion, I would put the conversion logic in the domain. And it's not over kill because it's your business domain.